# Do users have to be associated with the schema that app is in, in order to use it in an app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection

I'm having problems making a test user account access the database for a new app we're writing. Whenever I try to run the app I get the following error:

"The underlying provider failed on Open. Login failed for user OURDOMAIN\App.Test_User"

In trying to figure out what's wrong and looking for answers I came across this question posted here: [ADO.NET Connection String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589231/ado-net-connection-string). I then checked the database and found that every one of us on the development team's default schema is our own domain login (not sure what that does) and the database role we're all in adds us to db_owner. Seems to me like we'd have a pass on everything, whereas the user's default schema is dbo. They should at least also have access to the additional schemas our database and app uses. But that referenced article says that the connection string cannot specify the schema. So I'm no sure how we'd get to it using EF. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have Windows Authentication. This means, that a user logged into Windows is automatically logged into the database. But this does not mean that this user is automatically allowed to do things in the db. He also must have rights granted.

You can use default roles for this or create your own roles (and attribute them to the users) for more sophisticated scenarios. If you create your own roles, you must grant them rights for all objects these users can use. Example:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON MyTable TO AdvancedUserRole;
GRANT SELECT ON CustomersView TO AdvancedUserRole;

GRANT SELECT ON MyTable TO SimpleUserRole;
GRANT SELECT ON CustomersView TO SimpleUserRole;
```

If you are using default roles, users that are not `db_owner` need to be at least `db_reader` and possibly also `db_writer` if they are allowed to insert/update data.